# Custom Map Annotation Callout image

Tags: ios4, annotations, mapkit, callouts

I'm able to set the MKPinAnnotationView with title, subtitle, an image on the left (leftCalloutAccessoryView) and a button on the right (rightCalloutAccessoryView).

With this code i set the image on the left:

```
UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon.png"]];
myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10);
customPinView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = myImageView;
[myImageView release], myImageView = nil;
```

The result is something like this:
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0KcS.png)

but I would like to get something like this:
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvSzV.png)
where the image is aligned with the subtitle.

How can get it?

Thx.

Answer (score 1):

That's going to require using a custom annotationView. There's plenty of documentation about this in the developer resources. There's no way to do that image alignment using the default annotation style.